# WcfSvcHost throws LoaderException when attaching to IIS7 process, but everything seems to work?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been implementing RSA security for a project I am working on.

- I'm using the SecurID4Net files found on the web to get this rolling, which by default are targeted to the .Net 2.0 framework, ANY CPU.
- I created a derived SqlMembershipProvider which references the SecurID4Net.Interfaces project, targeting .Net 4.0, any CPU.
- My class lib "Services" references the SqlMembershipProvider, also targeting Any CPU.
- My web app "Services.Web" references the "Services" lib, .Net 4.0, Any CPU.

I'm not using the client profile for any assembly targeting .Net 4. Every reference I have described here has Copy Local set to True.

I have my local IIS default web site set up to my output folder for the web project, so I can Ctrl-Shift-B and browse my IIS folder. When my client app signs in for the first time (possibly 2 or 3 times), it works fine, but after that sign ins fail.  Additionally, when attaching to the IIS7 process (Services.Web), I would get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.LoadServiceAssembly(String svcAssemblyPath)
```

The DLL it is having problems loading is the SqlMembershipProvider I created.

So, I changed the SecurID4Net.Interfaces project to target .Net 4.0, and recompiled. It seems to work consistently now (still testing this part), but CTRL-ALT-P to attach to the IIS process still results in the WcfSvcHost error popping up before I can actually attach to the process... everything else seems to be working.

- I'm running my VS as admin so I can attach to an IIS process;
- All references described are set to Copy Local = true;
- All assemblies are targeting .Net 4.0 Full Profile;
- All assemblies are reachable, not blocked by the copy operation to the server where this is hosted;
- To my knowledge no syntax issues with the web.config.

Anyone have any ideas why this error keeps popping up? Why would this error pop up when everything seems to be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer almost immediately. After inspecting each AssemblyInfo.cs file in the chain of projects, I found this in my SqlMembershipProvider assembly:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("EN-us")]
```

I removed the value so it's an empty string.

I had a very similar issue in another project I worked on a few months ago where the web site had this filled in, and the web site worked on the very first load, but every load thereafter failed with a very cryptic error which, after drilling down, found that it could not load the assembly, giving a FileNotFoundException.

I don't know why this tiny, simple attribute would cause so many headaches...

EDIT: I'm 99% certain this was it. When I attach to my IIS process I no longer get a WcfSvcHost error.